# Drawable start icon gets blurry

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to show an icon at the left side of the `edittext` so, for that I am using the 24X24 sized icon to set as a `drawable` using `xml` as following

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/tv_email"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
   android:drawablePadding="20dp"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/email_white_24"
   android:hint="@string/hint_username"
   android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"
   android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textColorHint="@color/color_green_hint"
   android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_regular"/>
```

Similarly, I have also set `drawable` for other fields too. But, they are also getting blurred. I  have also tried using other sizes too. such as 16X16 and 32X32 size but using that too the icons are getting blurred. Do anyone has the solution? Please help.

Comment: can you show the preview?

Comment: are you using vector icons or pnj and jpg icons?

Comment: Create all sizes of icons and put in `mipmap` folder and access from it. Start with `24x24 (mdpi)` and export others icons size based on it.

Comment: @DEEPANSHU I am using png icons

Comment: please try to use vector images it will resolve your problem